# Custom Preference

Tags: android

I have my own preference

```
<Preference
android:key="testkey"
android:title="Test"
android:summary="test">
/Preference>
```

How i can start ProgressDialog with downloading from preference?

Answer (score 2):

You can start from here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/seekbar_preference.aspx